# Programmatically access Google Chrome bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome

How can I programmatically get (and manipulate) my bookmarks that are synced between different instances of Google Chrome using my Google account?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a JSON object stored in "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" folder. File name is Bookmarks

You can parse it using any JavaScript, Java (or any other language) Lib.

Hope that helps!

A related thread: [Manipulating Google Chrome bookmarks from external program (and make Chrome aware)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217994/manipulating-google-chrome-bookmarks-from-external-program-and-make-chrome-awar)